# Form select from a large tree of data

Tags: html, dojo

I have to select from around 2000 items in a form. The data is a tree - think of it as, say a directory tree and selecting one file from 2000 where each "directory" will only have at most ~ten items, but the tree itself is ~2000 items.

It is hard to select from and with the dojo items that I have seen that allow filtering, you have to be correct from the left-hand side as you type, but most of the distinguishing parts of each entry are to the right!

Do any of your filtering select tools replace filtering with a glob pattern or regexp?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Maybe add some code to describe the problem. The question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have interpreted your question as: You want to know if you can replace the filtering pattern in a FilteringSelect - so that it doesn't match from only the left-hand side.

Answer: Yes - You can override the search pattern using the queryExpr attribute. e.g. {queryExpr: '*${0}*'}